# Use enum instances in another class in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I have an enum class called *UsedPlatforms*:

```
from enum import Enum

class UsedPlatforms(Enum):
    PROD = 1,
    TEST = 2
```

I want to use this enum in another python class like:

```
import UsedPlatforms

def foo(platform):
    if platform == UsedPlatforms.PROD:
        print("Did it!")

foo(platform=UsedPlatforms.PROD)
```

But when I run second script, I get an **error** like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/EnumTest/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    foo(platform=UsedPlatforms.PROD)
AttributeError: module 'UsedPlatforms' has no attribute 'PROD'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think I couldn't import my enum class properly or I didn't know how to use enums between classes, or smth. So, what should I do to use my enum class in another classes?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need/want commas after the value or you'll get a `tuple` value -- i.e. `PROD == (1, )`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `enum` class contained in a file named `UsedPlatform.py`, then you should change your `import` statement in `test.py` to:

```
from UsedPlatforms import UsedPlatforms
```

If the file you are trying to import is inside a folder you need :

```
from folder.FileWithoutExtension import <ClassName/Enum>
```

[image]